# asp.net search engine for static application

Tags: asp.net

i dont have much knowledge about asp.net, i have to do one simple search engine for my web application(c# asp.net),all are static pages, and some folders consistson aspx and html files... plz help me...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let google do it for you with a custom search:

http://www.google.com/cse/

Comment: fair enough. would save you a lot of hassle though

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the popular [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) search engine. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/lucene-net-in-asp-net.aspx) is a codeproject article showing how to use it.